# Webform description allowing HTML

Tags: entities, webforms

I'd like to allow HTML in my webform field descriptions. I don't need an editor of some sorts; just the basics like  and  tags and stuff. How can I edit my webform to allow these tags in the description field?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the module [Webform HTML Textarea](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_html_textarea) might do what you're wanting. It allows you to use the site's input methods (Filtered text, plain text, etc.). So you could make a limited one for your users with only the options you need (bold, italic, underline, etc.).